# get element of selected value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get an element of a selected value using Jquery but I can only seem to pull the value.

In the following example I have HTML returned like this when I select a dropdown menu

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" style="max-height: 27px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 80px;">
    <li data-original-index="0" class="">
        <a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
            <span class="text">Bitcoin
                <small class="text-muted">BTC</small>
            </span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li data-original-index="1" class="selected">
        <a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="true">
            <span class="text">Ethereum
                <small class="text-muted">ETH</small>
            </span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to get the vaule of this element when it is selected from the dropdown each time it changes

> `<small class="text-muted">ETH</small>`

I have tried the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dropdown').on('change', function() {
        alert( $('option:selected', this).text() ); 
        alert( $(this).val()
    });
});
```

They only bring back the selected value each time I change the dropdown option (in the above codes case it would be Ethereum). Is there any way to get ETH instead? Thank you.

EDIT-

Sorry for the misunderstanding

Here is the example for a much better reference of how the select is populated - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xjVjra

If you require anything else just let me know

Comment: Please show your drop down menu code. It is unclear what you are trying to do. To get the value of the drop down's selected choice, you only need `this.value` in your `change` event handler.

Comment: I see no element with an id of dropdown

Comment: There aren't any `<option>`s in your code. Or anything that could have a  value.

Comment: please create snippet...

Comment: sorry it is got a school project, I am just starting out in this - let me make an edit and hopefully provide you with the correct code

Comment: Click `<>` and create a [mcve]